# saga is not triggered on synchronous api call

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using fetch api in my react redux application along with redux saga  ow problem is I have synchronus call in fetch api. but no my that call is not getting triggered through saga. below s my first call

```
import {fetchAggregatedData1,
  fetchAggregatedData2
} from '../actions/mixActions';
fetch(types.BASE_URL + types.DATA_URL).then(response => {
    var res=response.json();
    console.log('response',res)
    const maxYear = Math.max.apply(
        Math,
        res.map(function(data) {
          return data.year;
        })
      );
      console.log('trigered in api')
      fetchAggregatedData2(maxYear);
      fetchAggregatedData1(maxYear);

    return res;
```

below are my action

```
export function fetchAggregatedData2(year) {

  return {
    type: types.FETCH_AGGREGATED2,
    year
  };
}
export function fetchAggregatedData1(year) {
  return {
    type: types.FETCH_AGGREGATED1,
    year
  };
}
```

here is my saga index.js

```
    export default function* startForman() {


  yield [
fork(watchAggregate1),
    fork(watchAggregate2)
    ]}
```

in watchAggregate1.js

```
export default function* watchAggregate1() {
  yield takeLatest(types.FETCH_AGGREGATED1, aggregateSaga1);
}
```

anyone can let me know why synch call  is not going through??

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use action without dispatch function.

---

Within  saga use put() that instructs the middleware to dispatch an action to the Store

please, see code below,perhaps it will be helpful

**actions:**

```
const types ={
    FETCH_AGGREGATED1: 'FETCH_AGGREGATED1',
    FETCH_AGGREGATED_SUCCESS: 'FETCH_AGGREGATED_SUCCESS',
    FETCH_AGGREGATED2: 'FETCH_AGGREGATED2',
    FETCH_AGGREGATED_SUCCESS_2: 'FETCH_AGGREGATED_SUCCESS_2'


}

const fetchAggregatedData_1 = year => ({
    type: types.FETCH_AGGREGATED1,
    payload: year
})

const fetchAggregatedDataSuccess_1 =  year => ({
    type: types.FETCH_AGGREGATED_SUCCESS,
    payload:year
})

const fetchAggregatedData_2 = year => ({
    type: types.FETCH_AGGREGATED2,
    payload:year
  });

  const fetchAggregatedDataSuccess_2 = year => ({
    type: types.FETCH_AGGREGATED_SUCCESS_2,
    payload:year
  });
```

**api:**

```
 fetchApi = fetch('/api').then(response => response.json())
```

**sagas:**

```
function*aggregateSaga1({payload}){
   try{

    const resp = yield call(fetchApi);

    /**
     * your actions with response
     * 
     */
            const maxYear = 1;
     /**
      * 
      */

    yield put(fetchAggregatedDataSuccess_1(maxYear));
    yield put( etchAggregatedDataSuccess_2(maxYear));


   }catch(e){

   }

    }

 function * watchAggregate1(){
   yield takeLatest(types.FETCH_AGGREGATED1, aggregateSaga1);
 }



function* rootSaga(){
   yield[
       fork(watchAggregate1)
   ]

}
```